# How to complete C++ class etc. in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, delphi

I just started converting a library project from Delphi to C++ in VS2005.
How can I do simple things familiar from Delphi IDE like:

1. complete the C++ class (in Delphi Ctrl+Shift+C)
2. quick move from method declaration to its definition (in Delphi Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down)

Note: I must use VS2005 for this project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ IDEs don't have equivalent functionality to class completion. The IDE cannot complete classes because it does not know how to do so. Definitions can be provided in many places, in defining declarations, later in the same file, in another file, in a library.

To move from definition to declaration you can the F12 shortcut, also available from the menus.

Comment: 1. Ok I see but still completing a declaration from already present definition should be always possible (Delphi adds them to the end of private section). By default the automatic completion of definition should be also possible (search cpp file with same name and if found add definition as Delphi does).

Comment: Of course it would be usable only in that scheme (one *.h, one *.cpp, no special things you mentioned). Even Delphi class completer works incorrectly sometimes but is overall a great tool.

Comment: There's a lot more flexibility in C++ which makes this less predictable than Delphi. These are very different languages. Anyway, there's no such tool in VS so you'll have to do without.

Comment: @David - strictly speaking it comes down to the language personalities, not Visual Studio per se.  e.g. RemObjects Oxygene provides class completion (in Visual Studio) for Oxygene classes obviously, not C++.  The problem is the language (your accurate first point), not the particular IDE (presumably RAD Studio doesn't offer it either, for C++ ?  Though I don't know for sure since I've not used it myself).  Another example:  C# doesn't need class completion either since in that case there is no declaration separate from the implementation.